# Stub es6 getter setter with sinon

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, sinon

If you use the following es6 syntax for getters/setter

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name.toUpperCase();
  }

  set name(newName) {
    this._name = newName;
  } 
}
```

How would you stub the getter method ?

```
const john = new Person('john')
sinon.createSandbox().stub(john, 'name').returns('whatever')
```

Does not seem to be working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Github issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1095) led me to : [sinon js doc](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/)

`stub.get(getterFn)`

Replaces a new getter for this stub.

```
var myObj = {
    prop: 'foo'
};

sinon.stub(myObj, 'prop').get(function getterFn() {
    return 'bar';
});

myObj.prop; // 'bar'
```

`stub.set(setterFn)`

Defines a new setter for this stub.

```
var myObj = {
    example: 'oldValue',
    prop: 'foo'
};

sinon.stub(myObj, 'prop').set(function setterFn(val) {
    myObj.example = val;
});

myObj.prop = 'baz';

myObj.example; // 'baz'
```